# Turning Deeply-Nested JSON with Varying Number of Keys into a Flat DataFrame using R

Tags: json, r

I have a sample JSON file that I am trying to parse into a DataFrame in R.  I have tried multiple approaches, but I keep running into walls.

The JSON is a list of measurements, each with a recorded time and between 6 and 9 measurement metrics, each metric divided into three components (parameter, unit, value).

This is the sample JSON File:

```
[
  {
    "measurements": [
      {
        "parameter": "wind_direction",
        "unit": "degrees",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "parameter": "wind_speed",
        "unit": "meters_per_second",
        "value": 1.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "visibility",
        "unit": "meters",
        "value": 12000
      },
      {
        "parameter": "temperature",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 21.4
      },
      {
        "parameter": "dewpoint",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 4.7
      },
      {
        "parameter": "sea_level_pressure",
        "unit": "millibars",
        "value": 1009.3
      },
      {
        "parameter": "maximum_temperature_12h",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 27.4
      },
      {
        "parameter": "minimum_temperature_12h",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 7.4
      },
      {
        "parameter": "precipitation_24h",
        "unit": "millimeters",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    ],
    "recorded_at": "2017-11-23T00:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "measurements": [
      {
        "parameter": "wind_direction",
        "unit": "degrees",
        "value": 230
      },
      {
        "parameter": "wind_speed",
        "unit": "meters_per_second",
        "value": 1.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "visibility",
        "unit": "meters",
        "value": 10000
      },
      {
        "parameter": "temperature",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 14.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "dewpoint",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 7.2
      },
      {
        "parameter": "sea_level_pressure",
        "unit": "millibars",
        "value": 1010.7
      }
    ],
    "recorded_at": "2017-11-23T03:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "measurements": [
      {
        "parameter": "visibility",
        "unit": "meters",
        "value": 10000
      },
      {
        "parameter": "temperature",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 10.3
      },
      {
        "parameter": "dewpoint",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 5.7
      },
      {
        "parameter": "sea_level_pressure",
        "unit": "millibars",
        "value": 1012.9
      },
      {
        "parameter": "maximum_temperature_24h",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 27.4
      },
      {
        "parameter": "minimum_temperature_24h",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 7.4
      }
    ],
    "recorded_at": "2017-11-23T06:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "measurements": [
      {
        "parameter": "wind_direction",
        "unit": "degrees",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "parameter": "wind_speed",
        "unit": "meters_per_second",
        "value": 2.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "visibility",
        "unit": "meters",
        "value": 10000
      },
      {
        "parameter": "temperature",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 10.3
      },
      {
        "parameter": "dewpoint",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 2.7
      },
      {
        "parameter": "sea_level_pressure",
        "unit": "millibars",
        "value": 1017.0
      }
    ],
    "recorded_at": "2017-11-23T09:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "measurements": [
      {
        "parameter": "visibility",
        "unit": "meters",
        "value": 10000
      },
      {
        "parameter": "temperature",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 9.8
      },
      {
        "parameter": "dewpoint",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 0.1
      },
      {
        "parameter": "sea_level_pressure",
        "unit": "millibars",
        "value": 1019.3
      },
      {
        "parameter": "maximum_temperature_24h",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 27.4
      },
      {
        "parameter": "minimum_temperature_24h",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 8.6
      },
      {
        "parameter": "precipitation_24h",
        "unit": "millimeters",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    ],
    "recorded_at": "2017-11-23T12:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "measurements": [
      {
        "parameter": "wind_direction",
        "unit": "degrees",
        "value": 90
      },
      {
        "parameter": "wind_speed",
        "unit": "meters_per_second",
        "value": 1.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "visibility",
        "unit": "meters",
        "value": 12000
      },
      {
        "parameter": "temperature",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 12.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "dewpoint",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 4.8
      },
      {
        "parameter": "sea_level_pressure",
        "unit": "millibars",
        "value": 1021.5
      }
    ],
    "recorded_at": "2017-11-23T15:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "measurements": [
      {
        "parameter": "wind_direction",
        "unit": "degrees",
        "value": 160
      },
      {
        "parameter": "wind_speed",
        "unit": "meters_per_second",
        "value": 1.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "visibility",
        "unit": "meters",
        "value": 12000
      },
      {
        "parameter": "temperature",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 22.9
      },
      {
        "parameter": "dewpoint",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 4.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "sea_level_pressure",
        "unit": "millibars",
        "value": 1013.0
      }
    ],
    "recorded_at": "2017-11-23T21:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "measurements": [
      {
        "parameter": "visibility",
        "unit": "meters",
        "value": 12000
      },
      {
        "parameter": "temperature",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 18.4
      },
      {
        "parameter": "dewpoint",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 6.7
      },
      {
        "parameter": "sea_level_pressure",
        "unit": "millibars",
        "value": 1010.8
      },
      {
        "parameter": "maximum_temperature_12h",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 24.5
      },
      {
        "parameter": "minimum_temperature_12h",
        "unit": "celsius",
        "value": 7.0
      },
      {
        "parameter": "precipitation_24h",
        "unit": "millimeters",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    ],
    "recorded_at": "2017-11-24T00:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

My most recent attempt was as follows:

```
library(jsonlite)
json_file <- "./333.json"
result <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_file)
lst <- lapply(result$measurements, unlist)
df <- as.data.frame(lst)
```

But the varying number of parameters for each measurement has me thrown.
Ultimately, I am wanting the final data to look something similar to:

```
ReceivedTime           wind_direction     wind_speed    visibility   temperature   dewpoint   sea_level_pressure   maximum_temperature_12h   minimum_temperature_12h   precipitation_24h
2017-11-23T00:00:00Z   100   1.0  12000  21.4   4.7  1009.3   27.4    7.4   0.0
2017-11-23T03:00:00Z   230   1.0  10000  14.0   7.2  1010.7   NULL    NULL  NULL
2017-11-23T06:00:00Z   NULL  NULL 10000  10.3   5.7  1012.9   27.4    7.4   NULL
...
...
...
So forth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy to use the `tidyverse` you could first `spread` measurements out so they are each in a single row in a wide format and then `unnest` the result:

```r
library(tidyverse)
result %>% 
  mutate(measurements = map(measurements, function(x) { 
    x %>% select(-unit) %>% spread(parameter, value) })) %>%
  unnest() %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 8 x 12
#>            recorded_at dewpoint maximum_temperature_12h
#>                  <chr>    <dbl>                   <dbl>
#> 1 2017-11-23T00:00:00Z      4.7                    27.4
#> 2 2017-11-23T03:00:00Z      7.2                      NA
#> 3 2017-11-23T06:00:00Z      5.7                      NA
#> 4 2017-11-23T09:00:00Z      2.7                      NA
#> 5 2017-11-23T12:00:00Z      0.1                      NA
#> 6 2017-11-23T15:00:00Z      4.8                      NA
#> 7 2017-11-23T21:00:00Z      4.0                      NA
#> 8 2017-11-24T00:00:00Z      6.7                    24.5
#> # ... with 9 more variables: minimum_temperature_12h <dbl>,
#> #   precipitation_24h <dbl>, sea_level_pressure <dbl>, temperature <dbl>,
#> #   visibility <dbl>, wind_direction <dbl>, wind_speed <dbl>,
#> #   maximum_temperature_24h <dbl>, minimum_temperature_24h <dbl>
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect!  Now I need to dissect this to learn a whole lot more about how to use this in other instances.  Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction.  Off to Google...